# How to keep custom view in bottom after changing parent height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, ondraw

I have custom view set to bottom and it's parent height is 200dp initially. when i click on the custom view, i have to set parent to be match parent. so that later i will animate custom view on full screen.

what is happening is, when i set size of relative layout (parent view) to match parent programmatically, it's child - custom view will also move upwards . how i can over come this ?

Below is layout definitions :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlTreatmentDone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:gravity="bottom">


    <com.firsttreatmentflow.doneTreatment.DoneControllerView
        android:id="@+id/doneViewController"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:minHeight="200dp"></com.firsttreatmentflow.doneTreatment.DoneControllerView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llArrowText"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivUpArrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/tvDone"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_up"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/tvDone"
            style="@style/BodyBoldTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottomReferenceView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Done"
            android:textColor="@color/uikit_white"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

now on click of custom view, i am changing layout height as below

```
llArrowText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            rlTreatmentDone.setLayoutParams(params);



            doneViewController.setStartControllerClicked(true);
        }
    });
```

this will move custom view as below 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your code you've set the LayoutParams Height to `WRAP_CONTENT` instead of `MATCH_PARENT` which I guess is what you were actually intending to do? Which would make `"@+id/rlTreatmentDone"` smaller and move it's childview upwards.

Comment: No, it is not working by changing to Match parent, i want to keep custom view to be bottom